# com.sun.btrace.VerifierException: Unsafe mode, requested by the script, not allowed

Tags: btrace

ubuntu 13.10

btrace 1.2.4

i have edit `-Dcom.sun.btrace.unsafe=true` param and assigned `@BTrace( unsafe = true )`

but when i run btrace script, it throw a exception:

> btrace 1625 ProductRPCNewBtrace.java
>
> > DEBUG: btrace debug mode is set
> >
> > DEBUG: btrace unsafe mode is set
> >
> > DEBUG: assuming default port 2020
> >
> > DEBUG: assuming default classpath '.'
> >
> > DEBUG: compiling ProductRPCNewBtrace.java
> >     DEBUG: compiled ProductRPCNewBtrace.java
> >
> > DEBUG: attaching to 1625
> >
> > DEBUG: checking port availability: 2020
> >
> > DEBUG: attached to 1625
> >
> > DEBUG: loading /export/servers/btrace/build/btrace-agent.jar
> >
> > DEBUG: agent args:
> >
> > > port=2020,debug=true,unsafe=true,systemClassPath=/export/servers/jdk1.6.0_25/lib/tools.jar,probeDescPath=.
> >
> > DEBUG: loaded /export/servers/btrace/build/btrace-agent.jar
> >
> > DEBUG: registering shutdown hook
> >
> > DEBUG: registering signal handler for SIGINT
> >
> > DEBUG: submitting the BTrace program
> >
> > DEBUG: opening socket to 2020
> >
> > DEBUG: sending instrument command
> >
> > DEBUG: entering into command loop
> >
> > DEBUG: received com.sun.btrace.comm.ErrorCommand@3c24c4a3
> >
> > > com.sun.btrace.VerifierException: Unsafe mode, requested by the script, not allowed
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.runtime.Verifier.reportError(Verifier.java:385)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.runtime.Verifier.reportError(Verifier.java:376)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.runtime.Verifier$1.visit(Verifier.java:141)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.runtime.InstrumentUtils.accept(InstrumentUtils.java:66)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.runtime.InstrumentUtils.accept(InstrumentUtils.java:62)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.agent.Client.verify(Client.java:397)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.agent.Client.loadClass(Client.java:224)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.agent.RemoteClient.(RemoteClient.java:59)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.agent.Main.startServer(Main.java:379)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.agent.Main.access$000(Main.java:65)
> > >           at com.sun.btrace.agent.Main$3.run(Main.java:166)
> > >           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
> >
> > DEBUG: received com.sun.btrace.comm.ExitCommand@11e9c82e

i open the debug mode, and we can see that i have open the unsafe mode.but why still not support unsafe mode??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it after restarting the application.

and i have proved it by changing `-Dcom.sun.btrace.unsafe=false`,and still can run in the unsafe mode. and then restart the application, run the same btrace script again,the same exception thrown.